# Icons in Android toolbar not crisp

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I am trying to get few icons on my toolbar. I have my icons `24 pixels png` in my `drawable` folder. The icons are of the right size but they are not crisp and clear. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I also tried using icons with `34 pixels`, they are large and still not clear. How can I get smaller clear icons? Below is the screenshot for the same.
[image]

Is is anything related to creating other drawable folder or something?

Comment: 24px png is too small. Toolbar icon size should be 48dp.

Comment: @Apurva for material design they should be 24dp, not 48dp https://material.google.com/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-touch-target-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will use 24px icons in xxxhdpi device, there could be problems, because 1px not always equals 1dp in Android. In fact there is an image, that shows dependency of difference between dp and px and densities:

[image]

More info you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources).

So, returning to your question, the answer is: your icons must be with 24 **DP** size, not 24 **PX** size.

Now table (first is density, second is px equality of 24dp):

- mdpi = 24px
- hpdi = 36px
- xhdpi = 48px
- xxhdpi = 72px
- xxxhdpi = 96px

So you need to provide those 5 resolutions of your image, in appropriate drawable folders and that's it. Problem solved.

**P.S.:** You can use Support Vector Drawables and provide one xml file per icon (instead of 5 png-s per icon), those you will reduce app size and provide scale-able icon for all screens in the world. More info [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your icons in drawable-hdpi Folder and remove from drawable  .ithink its work for you